# Cannot move to the tabbed layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I just created a new activity from eclipse new Android-file wizard. I created the activity with tabbed navigation. But when I try to move to that activity from my main activity, the application crashes with an error: `unfortunately myAppName has stopped`

On my main activity, on click of a button, I want to take the user to a tabbed activity. I am using the following code to move them to the next activity:

```
Intent calActivityIntent = new Intent(this, CalendarActivity.class);
this.startActivity(calActivityIntent);
```

Is there something wrong with this code?
As I added the tabbed activity through eclipse wizard, I am assuming the code of that new activity will be correct.

### Edit:

LogCat:

```
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3071)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14319)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3066)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    ... 11 more
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    at com.example.MyAppName.MainActivity.mainMenuButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:94)
01-14 18:42:15.770: E/AndroidRuntime(23918):    ... 14 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myappname"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myappname.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myappname.CalendarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_calendar" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note: the activity named 'CalendarActivity' is the tabbed activity.

Comment: show your logcat, AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov .. Added to OP

Comment: ok, now show your MainActivity class and mainMenuButtonClicked method

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov .. never mind .. I had a very silly mistake in mainMenuButtonClicked() method. I was using a variable in this method. I commented out the initialization of that variable or some reason during testing. Later on I forgot to un-comment that. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is in your logcat output:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at  com.example.MyAppName.MainActivity.mainMenuButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:94)
```

The problem is in the `mainMenuButtonClicked()` method from `MainActivity`. If you want exactly, post the code for this method.

Cheers!

Comment: Never mind .. I had a very silly mistake in mainMenuButtonClicked() method. I was using a variable in this method. I commented out the initialization of that variable or some reason during testing. Later on I forgot to un-comment that. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.